# spring-integration-kafka config consumer to receive message from specify partition

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I started using spring-integration-kafka in my project, and i can produce and consume messages from Kafka. But now, i want to produce message to specific partition and also consume message from specific partition.

Example i want to produce message to partition 3, and the consume will only receive message from partition 3.

Until now, my topic has 8 partitions, and i can produce message to specific partition, but i have not found the way to config the consumer only receive message from specific partition yet.

So any suggestion on how should i config the consumer with spring-integration-kafka, or anything else need to do with the KafkaConsumer.java class for it can receive message from specific partition.

Thanks.

Here is my code:

the kafka-producer-context.xml

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="inputToKafka" />

<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" kafka-producer-context-ref="kafkaProducerContext"
    auto-startup="true" order="1" channel="inputToKafka" />
<int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext"
    producer-properties="producerProps">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration 
            broker-list="127.0.0.1:9092,127.0.0.1:9093,127.0.0.1:9094"
            async="true" topic="testTopic"
            key-class-type="java.lang.String" 
            key-encoder="encoder"
            value-class-type="java.lang.String" 
            value-encoder="encoder"
            partitioner="partitioner"
            compression-codec="default" />
    </int-kafka:producer-configurations>
</int-kafka:producer-context>

<util:properties id="producerProps">
    <prop key="queue.buffering.max.ms">500</prop>
    <prop key="topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms">3600000</prop>
    <prop key="queue.buffering.max.messages">10000</prop>
    <prop key="retry.backoff.ms">100</prop>
    <prop key="message.send.max.retries">2</prop>
    <prop key="send.buffer.bytes">5242880</prop>
    <prop key="socket.request.max.bytes">104857600</prop>
    <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes">1048576</prop>
    <prop key="socket.send.buffer.bytes">1048576</prop>
    <prop key="request.required.acks">1</prop>
</util:properties>

<bean id="encoder"
    class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.common.StringEncoder" />

<bean id="partitioner" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.support.DefaultPartitioner"/>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="5"
    keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500" />
```

the KafkaProducer.java

```
public class KafkaProducer {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(KafkaProducer.class);

@Autowired
private MessageChannel inputToKafka;

public void sendMessage(String message) {

    try {
        inputToKafka.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message)
                    .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "testTopic")
                    .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.PARTITION_ID, 3).build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(String.format(
                "Failed to send [ %s ] to topic %s ", message, topic),
                e);
    }
}
```

}

the kafka-consumer-context.xml

```
<int:channel id="inputFromKafka">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="kafkaMessageExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<int-kafka:zookeeper-connect id="zookeeperConnect"
    zk-connect="127.0.0.1:2181" zk-connection-timeout="6000"
    zk-session-timeout="6000" zk-sync-time="2000" />

<int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="kafkaInboundChannelAdapter" kafka-consumer-context-ref="consumerContext"
    auto-startup="true" channel="inputFromKafka">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="10" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"
        max-messages-per-poll="5" />
</int-kafka:inbound-channel-adapter>


<bean id="consumerProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="auto.offset.reset">smallest</prop>
            <prop key="socket.receive.buffer.bytes">1048576</prop>
            <prop key="fetch.message.max.bytes">5242880</prop>
            <prop key="auto.commit.interval.ms">1000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<int-kafka:consumer-context id="consumerContext"
    consumer-timeout="1000" zookeeper-connect="zookeeperConnect"
    consumer-properties="consumerProperties">
    <int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:consumer-configuration
            group-id="defaultGrp" max-messages="20000">
            <int-kafka:topic id="testTopic" streams="3" />
        </int-kafka:consumer-configuration>
    </int-kafka:consumer-configurations>
</int-kafka:consumer-context>

<task:executor id="kafkaMessageExecutor" pool-size="0-10"
    keep-alive="120" queue-capacity="500" />

<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="inputFromKafka"
    ref="kafkaConsumer" method="processMessage" />
```

the KafkaConsumer.java

```
public class KafkaConsumer {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

@Autowired
KafkaService kafkaService;

public void processMessage(Map<String, Map<Integer, List<byte[]>>> msgs) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Integer, List<byte[]>>> entry : msgs
            .entrySet()) {
        log.debug("Topic:" + entry.getKey());
        ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, List<byte[]>> messages = (ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, List<byte[]>>) entry
                .getValue();
        log.debug("\n**** Partition: \n");
        Set<Integer> keys   = messages.keySet();
        for (Integer i : keys)
            log.debug("p:"+i);
        log.debug("\n**************\n");
        Collection<List<byte[]>> values = messages.values();
        for (Iterator<List<byte[]>> iterator = values.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            List<byte[]> list = iterator.next();
            for (byte[] object : list) {
                String message = new String(object);
                log.debug("Message: " + message);
                try {
                    kafkaService.receiveMessage(message);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(String.format("Failed to process message %s",
                            message));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

So my problem is here. When i produce message to partition 3 or any partition, the KafkaConsumer always receive the message. All what i want are: the KafkaConsumer will only receive message from partition 3, not from other partition.

Thanks again.

Comment: I encountered a problem like you. have you found any solution?

Comment: I also want to integrate Kafka with Spring, can you please share any repo from where I can download working codes

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [message-driven-channel-adapter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka#message-driven-channel-adapter).

> As a variant, the KafkaMessageListenerContainer can accept org.springframework.integration.kafka.core.Partition array argument to specify topics and their partitions pair.

You need to wire up a listener container, using [this constructor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L130) and provide it to the adapter using the `listener-container` attribute.

We'll update the readme with an example.

Comment: Thanks Gary, i'm trying to do it and waiting for example.

Comment: Hi Gary, it seems the message-driven-channel-adapter uses the Kafka SimpleConsumer. So my question is: Can i able to config consumer to receive message from specify partition in Kafka High-level Consumer?  Because i have multiple consumers. Thanks.

Comment: No; to select specific topics you need the message-driven adapter.

Comment: Hi Gary. I have one more issue is: when i try to send about 10 messages per 1 second, look seem the consumer can receive message immediately. But when i try with a large size, about 500mess/1sec, the consumer has a delay time, about 3 -5 sec to start receive message. I don't know why. Do you have any idea or suggestion to help me resolve this issue? Thanks so much.